# how do i know position of point, perpendicular to line

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

There are 2 Point A(a,b,c), B(d,e,f)

[image]

There is the line AB, connecting A and B

Line CC' is perpendicular to line  AB

I want to Point C 's position on line CC'

If length of line CC' is 1, what is C 's position?

How do I calculate C's position with unity?

> A : Vector3(a,b,c)
>
> B : Vector3(d,e,f)
>
> AC' length = BC' length
>
> CC' length = 1
>
> AB is perpendicular to CC'
>
> -> C Vector3(?,?,?)

Comment: Do you know the point C'? It is impossible to determine C without some information about C', such as the exact coordinates or how far along the line AB it is positioned. Can you please clarify what information you know and what you want to find exactly.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please clarify. Do you already know the line CC'? Are you talking about 2D or 3D points and lines? If 3D, in which angle is line CC' positioned with respect to AB?

Comment: Thank you for your interest
I supplement the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you describe it, the problem is undetermined. There are infinitely many solutions for `C` because you are working in 3D space. To visualize, imagine the point `C` orbiting around the axis `AB`. Regardless of where `C` is in its orbit, it will always be orthogonal to AB and `length(CC') = 1`. You need to further constrain the problem.

## The Mathematics

First, we calculate the point `C'`. To do this, we take the vector from `A` to `B`, which is `AB = B - A`. Then, to get to `C'` we just travel half the distance of `AB` from point `A`:

`C' = A + AB/2`

Now we need to find a vector orthogonal to `AB`. Here we encounter the problem that I described initially. There are infinitely many such vectors so we need to further constrain the problem. Suppose that we can choose a vector `v` that is not colinear to the lines `AB` or `C'C`. Now we can find `C'C` by finding a vector orthogonal to both `AB` and `v`.

We know that the cross-product of two linearly independent vectors produces a vector that is orthogonal to both vectors. So all that is left to do is normalize the result so that the length is 1:

`C'C = normalize(AB x v)`

Finally, we can find point `C` by traveling from `C'` along the vector `C'C`:

`C = C' + C'C`

## Unity Code

Here, I provide some untested code that simply implements the mathematics described above. I'm not awfully familiar with Unity so it is quite possible that there exists some built-in functions that would relieve some of the work:

```
Vector3 v = new Vector3(0, 0, 1); // Choose this as you wish
Vector3 AB = B - A;
Vector3 C_prime = A + AB / 2;
Vector3 C = C_prime + Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.cross(AB, v));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
this is exactly what I want.